How to compute the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}{\frac{\cos^{-1} (1-x^2)}{x}}$?
Let $$L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}{\dfrac{\cos^{-1}(1-x^2)}{x}}$$
I tried substituting $x=\sin \theta$ then,
$$L=\lim\limits_{\theta \to 0^+}{\dfrac{\cos ^{-1} (\cos^2 \theta)}{\sin \theta}}$$
But I don't know how to approach further.
Using a graphing calculator, $L=\sqrt{2}$.
[$\cos ^{-1}x=\arccos x$]

Can you see that $L = f'(0)$ for $f(x) = \arccos(1-x^2)$ ?

@MartinR But $\arccos(1-x^2)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$

But the one-sided derivatives to exist.

@MartinR If I differentiate $f(x)=\arccos(1-x^2)$, then will $L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}{f'(x)}$ ?

Letting $u=\cos^{-1}(1-x^2)$ we have $u\to 0^+$ when $x\to 0^+$, and $x=\sqrt{1-\cos(u)}$.
The limit transforms into $$\lim_{u\to 0^+} \dfrac{u}{\sqrt{1-\cos(u)}}$$
Using the known limit $$\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos(t)}{t^2/2}=1$$
we have $$\lim_{u\to 0^+} \dfrac{u}{\sqrt{1-\cos(u)}}=\lim_{u\to 0^+} \dfrac{u}{\sqrt{u^2/2}}=\lim_{u\to 0^+}\dfrac{u}{u/\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}$$

One can also use that $\sqrt{1-\cos(u)} = \sqrt 2 \cdot \sin(u/2)$ for $0 \le u \le 2 \pi$.

Yes, that is another option; that would lead to using that $\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\to 1$.

Solving $u=\cos ^{-1}(1-x^2)$ for $x^2$ we get, $x^2=1-\cos u$ then $|x|=\sqrt{1-\cos u}$, Therefore, $x= \pm \sqrt{1-\cos u}$. @JulioPuerta Have you selected the positive solution here because $x \to 0^+$ ?

Yes, $x> 0$, so necessarily $x=\sqrt{1-\cos(u)}$.

$f(x) = \arccos(1-x^2)$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ and differentiable on $(0, 1]$ with $f(0) = 0$. So the task is to compute
$$
 L = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{x}
$$
if that limit exists.
For $0 < x \le 1$ is
$$
 f'(x) = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-(1-x^2)^2}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2-x^2}} \, .
$$
and therefore, using the mean-value theorem,
$$
 \frac{f(x)}{x} = f'(c_x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2-c_x^2}}
$$
for some $c_x \in (0, x)$. Now $x \to 0$ implies $c_x \to 0$ and $f'(c_x) \to \sqrt 2$. It follows that
$$
\boxed{L = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \sqrt 2 \, .}
$$
(This is the right derivative of $f$ at $x=0$, i.e. $L = f_+'(0)$.)

Using L'Hôpital's rule we have that
$$\lim_{x\downarrow0}\frac{\arccos(1-x^2)}{x}=\lim_{x\downarrow0}\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-(1-x^2)^2}}=\lim_{x\downarrow0}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}.$$
